Django parse url differently
I have an url, that contains a semicolon: /?a=3;4.
I want to make request.GET['a'] output 3;4, right now it is 3.
Is it possible?
Thank you.
Python3.8, Django 3.1

Please add more details about python and django version. I tried it with django 4.2 and request.GET['a'] return 3;4

@FedeG, I have added the versions.

I'm testing, I'll respond to you in 1 minutes

Yes, in django 3.1 and python 3.8 the ; character breaks the querystring.
You have two ways to solve it:

Replace it with %3B, like so /?a=3%3B4
Parse the query string manually

Example for parse the qs manually:
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

query_string = request.META['QUERY_STRING']
params = parse_qs(query_string, keep_blank_values=True)
a_value = params.get('a', [''])[0]

